# How can I prevent a site from putting cookies in my site through an image?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am embedding a photobucket image on my site. Unfortunately, when I look at what cookies my site uses, I find that photobucket has forced their cookies onto my site. How can I remove the cookies from my site?

[image: CookieProblem]

Here is a codepen demonstrating the issue, and here is the relevant source code:

https://codepen.io/Thisisntme/pen/zNpvWP

```
<img src="https://i349.photobucket.com/albums/q394/123madskillz/logo_zpsohtpmz4i.png">
```

[image]

Is this normal phenomenon? Photobucket seems to put its cookies on stackoverflow when I link the image as well.

Answer (score 2):

They're not your cookies, they're not on your site, and you have no control over them. They're relating to another domain. They're being added to *your browser*, not your site.

If you don't want these things to show up don't use Photobucket. When you link to external assets you surrender all control over what those assets might do to someone's browser.

Comment: Hmm. I always thought that images were safe... I guess thats why adblock always blocks those 1x1 pixel images...

Comment: Nothing is safe. If you make a request for an external asset then that site can assign any cookies it wants. This is why some browsers have different levels of cookie permissions, like blocking cookie assignment for domains other than the one for the primary page.

Comment: Should I be ok with their cookies? Or should I switch hosting?

Comment: Personally I think sites like Photobucket are garbage, the user experience is atrocious. There's nothing you can't do there you can't do with other hosting options. [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is a paid service but the costs are almost inconsequential for small amounts of data. [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) is also an option for small projects. Hosting static files is also pretty easy on an inexpensive VPS you control, and then you can set your own cookie policy.

Comment: I'd save the image on your computer in the same folder as your html documents. Make a folder in that folder and call it images and change the link to something like <img src="images/logo_zpsohtpmz4i.png"> then upload the folder, the image and new html